# osgjs: How to speedup computeIntersections?

Tags: javascript

This is the chunk of code that draws line on 3d model of map (I'm not author)

```
StereoInteraction.prototype.onMouseMove = function (ev) {
  const hit = this.rayCast(ev);
  if (hit) this.drawContinue(hit);
};

StereoInteraction.prototype.rayCast = function (ev) {
  const x = ev.pageX - $(ev.target).offset().left;
  const y = ev.pageY - $(ev.target).offset().top;

  const ratioX = this.stereo.canvas.width / this.stereo.canvas.clientWidth;
  const ratioY = this.stereo.canvas.height / this.stereo.canvas.clientHeight;

  const hits = this.stereo.viewer.computeIntersections(x * ratioX, (this.stereo.canvas.clientHeight - y) * ratioY);

  hits.sort((a, b) => a.ratio - b.ratio);

  if (hits.length !== 1) return null;
  const point = hits[0].point;

  const worldPoint = osg.Vec3.create();
  this.reserveMatrixStack.reset();
  StereoUtils.transformMat4(worldPoint, point, osg.computeLocalToWorld(hits[0].nodepath.slice(0), true, this.reserveMatrixStack.get()));

  return worldPoint;
};
```

The problem is `this.stereo.viewer.computeIntersections` takes enormously much time (0.2 sec) ([on this line](https://github.com/cedricpinson/osgjs/blob/f49c62c7936596ea1c65cbfae5d85af1c1c74e96/sources/osgViewer/View.js#L237)) and I don't know why. Can someone give me a hint?

For example:

- can it be because of big scene?
- what is `traversalMask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add `KdTreeBuilder` after load

```
var treeBuilder = new osg.KdTreeBuilder({
    _numVerticesProcessed: 0,
    _targetNumTrianglesPerLeaf: 50,
    _maxNumLevels: 20
});
treeBuilder.apply(this._root);
```

[Example](https://github.com/cedricpinson/osgjs/blob/master/examples/picking/main.js#L85-L90)

[Thanks to jtorresfabra for his help](https://github.com/cedricpinson/osgjs/issues/905#issuecomment-343495856)